BitLocker Encryption Stuck on 0.9%
As the title says, bitlocker encryption for my drive is at 0.9%, after running for many combined hours.
Running many commands that interact with bitlocker or the drive hang the console and all other bitlocker services.
Info

Windows 10, drive is not the boot drive
The drive and data can still be accessed, but opening folders or files is very slow. Disk is at 100% active time in Task Manager; read/write mostly at 0, with the occasional ~1MB jump in read speed
Event log shows only a single encryption start event, and no other events in subsequent system reboots

It's worth noting none of the attempted fixes managed to make logs before hanging


Bitlocker is suspended on the drive, but far as I can tell this only keeps it unlocked
manage-bde -status print

    BitLocker Version:    2.0
    Conversion Status:    Encryption in Progress
    Percentage Encrypted: 0.9%
    Encryption Method:    XTS-AES 128
    Protection Status:    Protection Off
    Lock Status:          Unlocked
    Identification Field: Unknown
    Automatic Unlock:     Disabled



Attempted Fixes

Pausing with manage-bde -pause D:

Hangs


Resuming with manage-bde -resume D:

Hangs


"Turn Off Bitlocker"

Hangs


chkdsk /x (to dismount drive during disk check(?), don't understand how this one is supposed to work, but it appears commonly when I'm googling)

Can't run because drive is in use, by bitlocker
If I disable the bitlocker service, it runs, but returns no error, starting bitlocker afterwards shows no noticeable affect




Having  a drive only partially encrypted is obviously dangerous, even if you can access some of the files on it; it is likely to become corrupted, unreadable and locked. The safest (and fastest!) fix is to restore the drive from the last disk image. As to the cause of the issue, it could be drive hardware failure, locked files on the drive, or other cause.
